# Is there a cygwin privacy policy?

Tags: cygwin

Is there a privacy policy for [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/licensing.html)? My company's IT dept needs it before I can install Cygwin on my machine  and I can't find one anywhere. Does Cygwin collect information and give it to the developers or a third party? Is there an official doc I can point to that states it definitively?

Answer (score 0):

There is no collection of data of any type from Cygwin.

Paragraph #1 of
https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.about
clarifies the project scope.

All the source code is provided as mentioned on
https://cygwin.com/licensing.html

You can also ask the same on the cygwin mailing list
https://cygwin.com/lists.html